# Not able to add all elements of an array of new resources to the registry

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to add all the elements of an array to the registry on composer-playground using `getParticipantRegistry().addAll()` but it is adding just the first two elements to the registry not all the elements of the array. There are 4 elements in the array as seen in the console output but just first two elements are getting added to the registry.

code:

```
/**
 * Add Students
 * @param {org.paradox.participants.AddStudents} addStudents
 * @transaction
 */

async function addStudents(transaction) {
  var factory = await getFactory()
  var namespace = 'org.paradox.participants'
  var studentRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Students')
  var students = []
  for (var studentID of ['1', '2', '3', '4']) {
    var student = factory.newResource(namespace, 'Students', studentID)
    student.name = 'Student ' + studentID
    if (studentID % 2 != 0)
      student.subjects = ['Science', 'Maths']
    else
      student.subjects = ['SocialScience', 'English', 'Hindi']
    students.push(student)
  }
  console.log(students)
  studentRegistry.addAll(students)
}
```

console:

```
@JS : IdentityManager         :<ResourceManager>()      Binding in the tx names and impl 
main.0dbfc9903b7dba442744.bundle.js:1:937780
[…]
0: Object { "$namespace": "org.paradox.participants", "$type": "Students", "$identifier": "1", … }
1: Object { "$namespace": "org.paradox.participants", "$type": "Students", "$identifier": "2", … }
2: Object { "$namespace": "org.paradox.participants", "$type": "Students", "$identifier": "3", … }
3: Object { "$namespace": "org.paradox.participants", "$type": "Students", "$identifier": "4", … }
length: 4
__proto__: Array []
main.0dbfc9903b7dba442744.bundle.js%20line%201%20%3E%20Function%20line%203%20%3E%20eval:35:3
@JS : EngineTransactions      :createHistorianRecord()  created historian record 
main.0dbfc9903b7dba442744.bundle.js:1:937780
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `studentRegistry.addAll(students)` there should be an await keyword as `studentRegistry.addAll(students)` is an async method.
Finally the code should look something like this:

```
/**
 * Add Students
 * @param {org.paradox.participants.AddStudents} addStudents
 * @transaction
 */

async function addStudents(transaction) {
  var factory = await getFactory()
  var namespace = 'org.paradox.participants'
  var studentRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Students')
  var students = []
  for (var studentID of ['1', '2', '3', '4']) {
    var student = factory.newResource(namespace, 'Students', studentID)
    student.name = 'Student ' + studentID
    if (studentID % 2 != 0)
      student.subjects = ['Science', 'Maths']
    else
      student.subjects = ['SocialScience', 'English', 'Hindi']
    students.push(student)
  }
  console.log(students)
  await studentRegistry.addAll(students)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your model, but given that Students is :

```
participant Students identified by studentId {
  o String studentId
  o String name
  o String[] subjects
}
```

here is the code I used with Composer v0.16.x code using online Playground https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/:

```
 var factory = await getFactory();
 var namespace = 'org.paradox.participants';

  var students = [];

  var myArray = ["1","2","3","4"];


  for (var studentID in myArray) {

    var student = factory.newResource(namespace, 'Students', studentID);
    student.name = 'Student ' + studentID;
    if (studentID % 2 != 0) 
      student.subjects = ['Science', 'Maths'];
    else 
      student.subjects = ['SocialScience', 'English', 'Hindi'];

    students.push(student);

  } // end for

  console.log('student array is ' + students);
  return getParticipantRegistry(namespace + '.Students') 
      .then(function(studentRegistry) {
      studentRegistry.addAll(students)
  });
```

Comment: Ain't you doing the same thing?    
Previously I used two for loops to add students and the code was working fine but then I modified it a then surprisingly it stopped working properly.    
Can you provide any insights as to why the code is not working? According to me, they are the same thing.    

PS: js noobie here